# HTML Table not recognising line breaks from mysql database

Tags: php, html, database, html-table, line-breaks

I have a mysql database with an 'address' field (VARCHAR). I also have a html table that is used to display the addresses of different staff members.

My problem is that data is stored in the address field of the database with linebreaks between each line of the address, but when the data is displayed in the table the line breaks are not there, so the entire address is displayed on one line. How can I fix this?

I'm sure this is a question that is asked all the time, but I can't find the answer anywhere. I'm new to PHP so please forgive my naivety.

UPDATE:

This is basically my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$address  = $_POST['address'];

$queryupdate = "UPDATE Staff SET 
      address= :address WHERE id= :id";
$q = $db->prepare($queryupdate);
$q->execute(array(
        ":id"    => $id,
        ":address"  => $address));
```

The data in the `$address` variable is taken from a simple textarea.

Comment: remember html doesn't honor line breaks. they're treated as whitespace. You need to convert linebreaks to `<br />` tags, or use a `<pre>`-type system. e.g. use http://php.net/nl2br

Comment: HTML doesn't "do" line breaks. You need to insert an actual html code `<br /> ` in place of "\n"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual line breaks are never shown in HTML unless the `word-wrap` is set to `pre`, or an actual `pre` tag is used. However, to overcome this you can use the `nl2br()` functionality in PHP. What you'll need to do is use the `nl2br()` before outputting your data to the browser, and it will give you a HTML formatted string back where the line breaks are prepended by `<br>` tags.

See the documentation about `nl2br()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: You can do `$address = nl2br($_POST['address']);` if you want to solve it before it goes in the database, but preferably you would only use `nl2br()` for displaying only, not saving.

Answer (score 0):

Using help from @Boy :

I added 'nl2br' before the output of my string.